# Lookup only if foreign field is not null in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collections for articles and comments. Comment may have `articleId` (it is answer to article) or `parentId` (it is answer to another comment). There are only 2 levels, answer to another comment cannot have answer.

```
// articles
{ "_id": 100, "text": "Article text" } 

// comments
{ "_id": 1, "text": "First text", "articleId": 100 },
{ "_id": 2: "text": "Second text", "articleId": 100 },
{ "_id": 3, "text": "Third text", "parentId": 2 }
```

I would like find all **articles**, **comments** of articles and **answers** to comments.

```
db.getCollection("articles").aggregate([
    { "$match": {} },

    // Lookup comments of article.
    { "$lookup": { "from": "comments", "localField": "_id", "foreignField": "parentId", as: "comments" } },
    { "$unwind": { "path": "$comments", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },

    // Lookup answers to comments. There I need lookup only when foreignField is not null.
    { "$lookup": { "from": "comments", "localField": "comments._id", "foreignField": "parentId", "as": "comments.answers" } },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "comments": { "$push": "$comments" }, "text": { "first": "$text" } }
])
```

It works if the article has some comments. But if not, after first `lookup` (comments of article) article looks like this (empty array is ok):

```
{ "_id": 100, "text": "Article text", "comments": [] }
```

And after second `lookup` (answers to comments):

```
{
    "_id": 100,
    "text": "Article text",
    "comments": [{
        "answers": [
            { "_id": 1, "text": "First text", "articleId": 100 },
            { "_id": 2: "text": "Second text", "articleId": 100 }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Even if there are no comments, there are some answers to comments. I think it is because localField `comments._id` is `null` and foreignField `parentId` of these answers is also `null`. Is there any way to lookup only when foreignField is `not null`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below aggregation with mongodb **3.6** and above

```
Article.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "comments",
    "let": { "articleId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$articleId", "$$articleId" ] } } },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "comments",
        "let": { "commentId": "$_id" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$parentId", "$$commentId" ] } } }
        ],
        "as": "answers"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "comments"
  }}
])
```